# Is it possible to have multiple POM and TESTNG files in a project?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have the following setup:

Jenkins points to -> Pom.xml which points to -> Testng.xml

My goal is to have multiple jobs in Jenkins, each pointing to a different environment.  Those environments are currently separated by multiple TestNG files.  I have parameters setup in each testng.xml file which point the different environments.

Is there a way to have multiple POM files, each pointing to a different testng file?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a single pom file which defines a "profile" for each environment. The profile for an environment will customize all the configuration that is required for that environment (including pointing to the proper testng file).

In your pom, you will include

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>foo</id>
        <properties>
             ...
        </properties>
        <build>
             ...
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>bar</id>
        <properties>
             ...
        </properties>
        <build>
             ...
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and invoke it with

```
mvn -Pfoo
```

or

```
mvn -Pbar
```

As you say, you will want to have a Jenkins job per environment (with the -Pfoo in the configuration for that job) or you can have a single Jenkins job and pass the profile as a parameter to the job.

Comment: How would I add two or more profiles?  Would I have to copy/paste all my dependencies, repositories, reporting, etc to the other profiles? I don't see any examples on the web with multiple profiles.

Comment: @JasonKrept I updated the answer showing how to define and utilize two profiles. Just keep adding profile elements to add more profiles.

Comment: Thanks, Rob.  I started playing around with it some more and came up with the same solution.  Thanks for the edit as well.  Hopefully someone else will also benefit from the example.